# Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- DragListController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Here is my code. I got and error Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- DragListController. I'm still new with anuglar js

```
        angular
            .module('taskManager')
            .controller('DragListController', DragListController);

        DragListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', 'dragularService'];
        function DragListController($scope, $element, dragularService){

            var vm = this;
            vm.items = {};

            vm.todoList = [];
            vm.inProgList = [];
            vm.completedList = [];

            $scope.items = [];

            vm.init = function($element) {

                var database = firebase.database();
                database.ref('/task').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

                    $scope.$apply(function(){

                        vm.items = snapshot.val();
                        //Manipulating data from Firebase
                        angular.forEach(vm.items, function(value) {
                            angular.forEach(value, function(data){
                                if(data == 'completed'){
                                    vm.completedList.push(value);
                                }
                                if(data == 'to-do'){

                                    vm.todoList.push(value);
                                }
                                if(data == 'on the process'){
                                    vm.inProgList.push(value);
                                }
                            });
                        });

                        dragularService($element.children().eq(0).children(), {containersModel: vm.todoList});


                    });

                });


            }/*End of init function*/


            vm.init($element);

        }
```

Here is my app.js

```
    angular.module('taskManager', [
    'dragularModule',
    'ngRoute',
    'googlechart'
]);
```

Error: [$injector:unpr]
I'm using luckylooke/dragular for my app. Drag and drop functionality. Please help.

Here is my routes.js

```
    angular.module('taskManager')
    .config(function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/task',{
                templateUrl: 'views/task-view.html',
                controller: 'TaskListController as taskList',
                resolve: {

                }
            })
            .when('/',{
                templateUrl: 'views/task.html',
                controller: 'TaskListController as taskList'
            })
            .when('/all-list',{
                templateUrl: 'views/all-list.html',
                controller: 'TaskListController as taskList'
            })
            .when('/theme3',{
                templateUrl: 'views/theme3.html',
                controller: 'DragListController as dragList'
            });

    });
```

Comment: Im using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Okay i will try thanks

Comment: what is `$element`? where it is coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$element` is not a provider. It can't inject. It use in directive in link function. You will get directly in sequence of param `$scope, $element, attr, ctrl`. Don't try to inject `$element` in controller. Use directive if you can.

Comment: i didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

make sure in index.js you have included

```
<script src="<PATH TO DragListCtrl.js>"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/dragListController.js"></script>
Yes it has already